# neo4j create node if property of node does not match

Tags: node.js, neo4j

i have a node.js app where
i have to create a unique user based on the username property of a node
such as

```
(:USER {name:'username',password:'pass123'})
```

so i want to run a query that checks if a user with the given username exists or not and if not then create the node and set its password.

I am thinking about which way to go..
either create a CONSTRAINT or use CREATE UNIQUE ON MATCH ON CREATE  or first run a MATCH query and if it returns data then run CREATE query based on the result

i am using the neo4j-driver for node and the query run returns the result Obj

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `name` on :USER is meant to be unique in your model, so creating a unique constraint on this is the way to go.

As for the creation of the node itself, using [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/cypher/clauses/merge/) along with its ON CREATE clause should do the trick.

Comment: `MERGE (u:User {name:{username}} ) ON CREATE SET u.password = {password} `

Comment: however the result of the query is an object with properties that show how many nodes were created in the query.
So should i look for those value to find if a node was created or updated or is there any other better way

example:
```"updateStatistics":{"_stats":{"nodesCreated":1,"nodesDeleted":0,"relationshipsCreated":0,"relationshipsDeleted":0,"propertiesSet":2,"labelsAdded":1,"labelsRemoved":0,"indexesAdded":0,"indexesRemoved":0,"constraintsAdded":0,"constraintsRemoved":0}}```

Comment: @MichaelHunger how do i create a new relationship in the ```ON CREATE SET```?
i want to create a  node with a relationship if node does not exist

Comment: Can you provide more details about the node you want to create? Will this node have a relationship to the :USER node? Will a MERGE of the relationship work for you, or are there cases where there shouldn't be a relationship even if the :USER node exists?

Comment: @InverseFalcon 
`MERGE ( user:USER { userId : {userId} } ) - [:USERINFO]->(info:PROFILEINFO)
        ON CREATE SET user.password = {password} ,
                      info.firstName = {firstName} ,
                      info.lastName = {lastName} ,
                      user.username = {username} ,
                      user.userType = {userType} ,
                      info.email = {email},
                      user.userId = {userId}
        RETURN user`

Comment: @InverseFalcon this is my final query i want to create user only if their userid, email, username are unique.But this only achieves a unique userid
how can i add OR condition to find a node if it has any of the above values as same.
currently my userid value is the same as email

Comment: @InverseFalcon I haven't created a unique constraint on any values till now. So i guess i could just do that and not make a simple situation more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Yep, unique constraints plus merging with those unique fields (instead of just the `userId`) should do the trick.